# What causes the status bar overlap the view?

Tags: ios5

any idea why the status bar overlap the view after `presentModalViewController->dismissModalViewControllerAnimated`

[image]

Xcode: 4.2
SDK: iOS 5
deployment target: 3.2
ARC: ON

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    UIViewController* currentViewController = [self getCurrentViewController];
    return [currentViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}
```

change to:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    UIViewController* currentViewController = [self getCurrentViewController];
    return [currentViewController canRotate]; // the implement is exactly as same as shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
}
```

fix this issue, but I don't understand why.